# Three.js converting 3D vertex to 2D point on the canvas

Tags: three.js

I want to convert a 3D point (vertex of a face) to 2D canvas, so i can move a little point to it.
I'm using the following function which i found while searching for an answer, but it doesn't work. It always show the point in the middle of the screen..

```
            function toScreenXY( position, camera ) {
            var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
            var projector = new THREE.Projector();
            projector.projectVector( position , camera );
            var halfWidth = widthHalf =window.innerWidth / 2;
            var halfHeight = heightHalf = window.innerHeight / 2;

            vector.x = ( vector.x * widthHalf ) + widthHalf;
            vector.y = - ( vector.y * heightHalf ) + heightHalf; 


            return {
                 x: vector.x,
                 y: vector.y
            };


         }
```

The position is a vertex from a face. I also tried converting it first using:

```
v.setFromMatrixPosition( match.object.matrixWorld );
```

This is the geometry from where i get the faces (if it matters)

```
var pgeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 16384/1,16384/1,127,127 );
```

i also rotated the `plane.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;`

JSFIDDLE for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/waf6u7xp/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, it looks like you are not assigning a value to vector.x or .y before you add the halfwidth to it, try changing

```
        projector.projectVector( position , camera );
```

to

```
        vector = projector.projectVector( position , camera );
```

Search this tutorial for "projectVector":

http://zachberry.com/blog/tracking-3d-objects-in-2d-with-three-js/

Hopefully that gives you enough to tinker with it, although I don't think it solves it quite yet...

Comment: I was using that tutorial... and yes your answer fixes it :)